# Create an order on behalf of SKU owner automatically with stripe connect

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

In this example when an order is created in stripe and payment is made, the money goes to the api key owner.

```
require "stripe"
Stripe.api_key = "sk_tes*******"

Stripe::Order.create(
  :currency => 'usd',
  :items => [
    {
      :type => 'sku',
      :parent => 'sku_7GgX4LQpE5Y3Go'
    }
  ])
```

I would liketo have the money transferred to the owner of the sku so that I dont have to make different `Order.create` when sku of different owners are included in the items array.

I know I can pass a `stripe_account` hash to create order on the behalf of the owner. But is it possible to make the order on behalf of the owner of SKU without mentioning `stripe_account` hash? By that I mean stripe looks at the SKU and creates the order on behalf of the SKU owner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help someone with the same doubt. When you are building an ecommerce website which uses stripe connect for creating a marketplace , stripe provides an easy way to create Products,Skus,Orders,etc for the connected account . All you have to do is , pass uid of the connected account with the stripe create command. ie, `{stripe_account: <uid of connected account>}`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to pass the stripe_account hash to the create order api call. As without it Stripe would attempt to just create the order in your account, and there is no restriction in Stripe to say that the id of a SKU can't belong to multiple accounts.

Comment: I have used stripe_account hash for creating order. But I get No such Sku exist error. Why is it happening? When I dont pass the stripe_account hash, order is created. The product and sku are created in my eCommerce platform using stripe connect.

Comment: you need to create the product and the sku in the connected account. An order in a connected account does not have access to product's and sku's in your account